# loops help in basic python

Tags: python, loops

I am new to pythons and I am trying to work through the basics I am trying to create a random sequence of the cards in a deck however I keep getting this error when I run this program.

```
shuffledeck.apend(card[deck[index]])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apend'
```

any ideas?

```
>>>from random import randint
mylist = ["H","S", "C", "D"]
carddeck = []
shuffledeck = []
suit= -1
index = 0

>>>for x in range (1,5):
    suit = suit +1
    for x in range (1,14):`
        suitname = mylist[suit]
        carddeck.append(str(x) + " " + suitname)
>>>for x in range (51, -1, -1):
    index = randint(0,x)
    shuffledeck.apend(card[deck[index]])
    del carddeck[index]
```

Comment: Have you tried `append` with two `p` ?

Comment: Spelling counts. A human can guess that `apend` was meant to be `append`, but can't be sure, and Python can't guess at all. Using iPython for your REPL and any of the popular IDEs for your script editor may help—that way, they'll offer all of the "auto-completion" options so you don't have to remember or guess how to say what you wanted.

Comment: A comment on your code: Using `for x in…` inside another `for x in…` is usually a bad idea. It means you can't access the outer `x`. In this case, you didn't need that outer `x` at all—but that means you shouldn't have it in the first place. For example, if you just do `for suit in range(4):` you can get rid of the `suit = -1` and `suit = suit + 1`. Or, even better, `for suitname in mylist:` lts you get rid of `suit` entirely.

Answer (score 4):

Python [already supports this](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.shuffle) actually.

```
from random import shuffle
shuffle(deck)
```

your main problem here is you wrote `shuffledeck.apend(card[deck[index]])` instead of `shuffledeck.append(card[deck[index]])`
Notice the extra p.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `shuffle` changes `deck` in-place, while the OP's code makes a shuffled _copy_. Of course you can fix that pretty easily: `shuffledeck = carddeck[:]; shuffle(shuffledeck)`.

Comment: Also: `random` is one of those modules whose source is meant to be readable sample code. At the top of [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html), there's a link to the [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/random.py#L261), which is probably simple enough for a novice to understand.

Comment: Or use `random.sample`.